# bee migrate command not working

Tags: postgresql, go, beego

I am getting following error while running migrations. It was working fine. But when I dropped and created database again It is giving following error now.

```
$ bee migrate -driver="postgres" -
conn="postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/lerg_development?sslmode=disable"

2017/09/08 12:42:37 INFO     ▶ 0001 Using 'postgres' as 'driver'
2017/09/08 12:42:37 INFO     ▶ 0002 Using 
'postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/lerg_development?sslmode=disable' as 'conn'
2017/09/08 12:42:37 INFO     ▶ 0003 Running all outstanding migrations
2017/09/08 12:42:39 INFO     ▶ 0004 |> 2017/09/08 12:42:39 [I] start upgrade Lerg_20170903_194959
2017/09/08 12:42:39 INFO     ▶ 0005 |> must have one register DataBase alias named `default`
2017/09/08 12:42:39 ERROR    ▶ 0006 Could not run migration binary: exit status 2
```

Database connection seems to be fine with connection string provided.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue, any updates here?

Comment: Not really. For me it was happening when I used to do `dep ensure` . I ended up using https://github.com/rubenv/sql-migrate